# python sockets can't send multiple messages -- data is referenced before assignment--

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Hi i'm trying to send multiple messages to the tcp server but in my client i got an error that data is referenced before assignment. If i send one message there will be no error but if i try to send more than one it returns the error.

tcp server:

```
class Connect(object):

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except:
            print('socket cannot be created')
        server_address = ('169.254.34.240', 10000)
        #print('starting up: ' + server_address)
        self.sock.bind(server_address)
        self.sock.listen(1)

    def listen(self):
        while True:
            connection, client_address = self.sock.accept()
            print('client connected')
            try:
                data = connection.recv(16)
                print(data)
                if data == "STATUS":
                    connection.sendall("vision=ready")
                elif data == "MEASURE":
                    connection.sendall("vision=computing")
                elif data == "GET_RESULT":
                    connection.sendall("x=1.5,y=0.25,z=0.14,a=0.15")
                else:
                    connection.sendall("wrong command")
            finally:
                connection.close()


def main():
    connect = Connect()
    connect.listen()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

my tcp client which is sending messages:

```
class Connect(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        # Create a TCP/IP socket
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # Connect the socket to the port on the server given by the caller
        print('connecting to host')
        self.sock.connect(('169.254.34.240',10000))

    def send(self, command):
        try:
            message = command
            print('sending: ' + message)
            self.sock.sendall(message)
            amount_received = 0
                amount_expected = len(message)
                while amount_received < amount_expected:
                    data = self.sock.recv(16)
                    amount_received += len(data)
                    print('received: ' + data)
        finally:
            self.sock.close()
            return data

def main():
    connect = Connect()
    print connect.send("STATUS")
    print connect.send("MEASURE")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

so anyone an idea, i suppose i don't end correctly or something, i thought it had something to do about my while in the client?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: that data is referenced before assignment, but if i send one message like status it will print correctly if i send two messages it will call that error

Comment: Please edit the *full traceback of the error* to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `self.sock.close()` after each request without creating a new socket. You will need to create a new socket after each time you close it.

You can solve this by creating a connection per request as follows:

```
class Connect(object):

    def connect(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print('connecting to host')
        sock.connect(('127.0.0.1',10000))
        return sock

    def send(self, command):
        sock = self.connect()
        recv_data = ""
        data = True

        print('sending: ' + command)
        sock.sendall(command)

        while data:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            recv_data += data 
            print('received: ' + data)

        sock.close()
        return recv_data


def main():
    connect = Connect()
    print connect.send("STATUS")
    print connect.send("MEASURE")
```

Comment: No problem! You should look at Jan Vlcinsky answer as well. I modified the way you are reading data from the server. This allows you to read data of any length from the server, and not just data equal to the length of the message you sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Providing full stack trace would help, pointing to exact line, where is the problem present. Learn reading these stack traces, they look boring, but provide valuable information like source file and line where it comes from.

Reading your code I suspect, that it fails at `finally` block, where you `return data`.

`data` will not have assigned value in case, the `while amount_received < amount_expected` would not allow even the first round in the loop or if withing that loop would happen an exception on the line `self.sock.recv(16)`.

Btw.: you are assuming, that length of response will be the same as length of request, but your server does not provide responses with such length.